# Is there a way to add the date time stamp for the data refresh in AWS QuickSight dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is there a field or formula I can add to a narrative in QuickSight that will allow me to show the date/time the backing data was most recently refreshed automatically?

Answer (score 3):

If your data set is SQL based (Whether SPICE or direct query) then I would use custom SQL and add a column with the date time value for the time that the query was run.

This can be done by using something like the [NOW() function in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-now/).

Other than this workaround I don't think it is currently possible to get what you are looking for in QuickSight